# package ‘fpc’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)

Tags: r, package

package `fpc` is not available (for R version 3.5.3)

I have tried a few methods:

1. `github_pkgs <- c("cran/Rstem")`
   `install_github(github_pkgs)`
2. `install.packages("fpc", repos= 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')`
3. `install.packages("fpc_2.1-11.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL)`

Thank you if you can help me out of this loop...

None of them works

Comment: yeah, that one is my question and solution 2, but it didn't work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `fpc` package requires R version 3.6.0.  You can see that in the summary page of the package:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fpc/index.html

> Version:  2.1-11.2
>   **Depends:    R (≥ 3.6.0)** Imports:  MASS, cluster, mclust, flexmix, prabclus, class, diptest, mvtnorm, robustbase, kernlab, trimcluster,
>   grDevices, graphics, methods, stats, utils Suggests:  tclust,
>   pdfCluster Published: 2019-04-26 Author:  Christian Hennig

Comment: On my God, It never comes across my mind that I should update my R version. I was trying so many different ways to install. Thank you. It's working